# Dragging launch image to the Retina 4 Inch slot having no effect

Tags: ios, xcode

I've just created a new project and am dragging images onto the Lauch Images section of its target.

I've dragged one called Default@2x.png into the Retina 3.5 Inch place-holder but when I drag one called Default-568h@2x.png into the Retina 4 Inch placeholder nothing happens - it doesn't appear in that slot nor does Xcode say anything.

I've used this exact same image in other projects, why is Xcode silently rejecting it this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the image out onto the desktop.

Rename it to "blah.png".

Make sure there are no images in your project folder called Default-568@2x.png. Not in your Xcode project.

Now drag blah.png onto the 4" default image section in the build settings.

It will now move the image into the project folder and rename it to the correct name.

Don't try to rename it yourself or it gets stuck because there is already a file with the name it's trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I've resolved it by first deleting the placeholder (right click on it > delete) and then re-drag launch image again.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work however, as soon as I dragged my image into the empty slot then the slot became filled with blackness (rather than my image).